# How can I check if the value of a textarea has HTML in it using PHP?

Tags: php, html, textarea

How can I check if the value of a textarea has HTML in it using PHP?

I have read multiple posts, I tried the following:

```
if ($text != strip_tags($text))
    // text contains html
```

and tried

```
if (preg_match("/([\<])([^\>]{1,})*([\>])/i", $string)) { 
    echo "string contains html"; 
}
```

and some other regex. But all give the same result. **If I enter only one line (without html)** in the textarea and validate it **it is fine**, it says there is no HTML. **If I enter more lines (even without html tags) it says there are html tags but there aren't**. Is there a transparent `<br>`? Even when I echo/verify the string no html tag is shown.

How come when I have multiple lines in a textarea without html chars it automatically says there are? Are there any other ways of verifying if there are html tags in a textarea?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to see if there are HTML tags in the text area?  Because you want to remove them?

Comment: I want to prevent users from entering html tags in the textarea. Because not everybody listens, I want to echo an "error" message when html tags are entered. After I will strip_tags()...

Comment: I am sure the problem is related to \n \r <br /> ^M ... As when I count the chars in javascript I don't get the same character count as with php. Php counts those brs or \n \r <br /> ^M...

Comment: I thought it was the linebreaks, but even if I remove all of them, it still detects html tags even if there are not.

Comment: Which method are you using, and have you tried `var_dump`ing the output from each operand in the `if` conditional to inspect their values?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like

```
if($text!=htmlspecialchars($text))
{ echo 'This contains HTML tags!!'; }
```

This should not care about the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
    $string_checked = str_replace("<", "#LESSTHAN#", $string);
```

Not only will it check the code for HTML, it'll convert to another character (or characters) so that the user CAN submit it, but it can be made harmless.

For instance, converting < to #LESSTHAN# will allow you to write it to a database and then retrieve it with no problem...and unless that string is going back into a textarea that is editable, you can choose to leave it as-is. If you want a user to be able to see his original HTML tags he entered, simply convert the string back before placing it in the pre-filled textarea.

```
    $string_checked = str_replace("#LESSTHAN#", "<", $string);
```

This would even allow you to permit certain HTML tags to be used (like bold, italic, etc.) that can't possibly do any real damage to the way an HTML page works (wouldn't break a form is what I mean).

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter more lines in a textarea the "wrapper" will add an (invisible) carriage return, so a invisible html code is added to your text. Try using one of the wrap methods below and see if it works.

```
<textarea name="userInput" cols="40" rows="6" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
```

Try to set the wrap method to: virual, hard, soft, physical or off